# matplotlib contour not encapsulating the limits as expected

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a figure that shows both a heatmap and a contourplot of the same data.

Currently the contour does not connect to the edges of the image, leaving the '6's and '8's at the edge of the plots out of the contour plot.

I would want the contour to actually enclose all the values containing the values specified in the `levels`.

```py
# make array
a = np.array(   [(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 (2,3,4,5,6,7),
                 (3,4,5,6,7,8),
                 (4,5,6,7,8,9),
                 (5,6,7,8,9,10)])

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4.5))

#plot both colors and contour
im = ax.pcolormesh(a,norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=10),
                cmap='rainbow')
contour = ax.contour(a,levels=[2,4,6,8],colors='k')

# indicate the data
for i in range(0,6):
    for j in range(0,5):
        plt.text(i+.5,j+.5,str(a[j,i]))
```

Figure showing heatmap and contours:

[image: figure showing heatmap and contours]

**UPDATE:**
I've provisionally solved the problem by enlarging the dataset and zooming  in on the original frame.

Comment: The coordinates for `pcolormesh` are the nodes of the quadrangles, while the coordinates for `contour` are the cell centres. Hence the offset you see in your plot

Comment: As example, the point (0,5) is not part of your data, so it cannot be connected by the contours.

Comment: Yes, I figured it would be something like that. I cannot find a way to change this setting however. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not a setting. This has to do with how you would like to extrapolate the data, which isn't possible with contours.

Comment: But I would guess that you come closer to your desired plot by using `imshow` instead of `pcolormesh`, something like `ax.imshow(a, aspect="auto")`